# Number of possibile combinations of distributing 6 apples to 3 persons under three different assumptions

Tags: combinatorics

I have 6 apples. These apples are the same, they do not differ. I have 3 persons.

Now I want to distribute the 6 apples to the 3 persons, under the assumption that

**a)** All the apples have to be given away

**b)** assumption a is not necessary, so I can give for example. 1 apple to Person A and no apples to Person B and C. I do not have to give away an apple to a person and I can also hand out completely none.

**c)** assumption a is not necessary, but each person has to get at least one apple.

### For assumption a) I thought I draw it in a table:

[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnkkV.png)

Now first of all I am not sure if I did it right. I end up with 28 possible different ways to distribute the apples.

**Question1: Is this right?**

But more important:

**Question2: What is the name of this kind of problem?**

For solving it I only found the stars and bars method and the theorem 2. According to this my n is 6 and k is 3, which gives me

[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWvq.png)

And indeed I get 28. But I am not sure.

**Question3: How would the assumption sound like (how would one formulate it), if it would be stars and bars theorem 1?**

### For assumption b)

I am also not sure, specifically because there are too much possibilites to draw it. I think it should be $n!/k!=6!/3!=6*5*4=120$.

**Question4: Is this really correct?**

**Question5: What is the correct name for this problem?**

I think it is "repetition not allowed, order does matter".

**Question6: How would the binomial coefficient be properly explained here?**

So $6!/3!=n!/k!$ is not equal to $\binom{n}{k}$. I am not sure but I think it should be $\binom{n}{n-k}=6!/3!$

**Question7: Suppose it would be a "repetition not allowed, order does not matter" problem. I have troubles to imagine this. How would this look like in this example?**

So I think it would be that I completely ignore the persons. I just ask myself, how many possibilites are there to distribute the apples in total. And I can distribute all of them (6), 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, or none. So I have 7 possibilites. This would be I can take 6 apples (or none) and I have one repetition. So

[ex3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMMIT.png)

I am not sure about the binomical coefficient in this case. The intention would be to say I have 6 apples and I have one repetition. However, this leads to only 6 possibilities, using the formula and binomial coefficient for this "repetition not allowed and without order" problem:

[ex4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5PvJ.png)

Or am I wrong an "repetition not allowed and without order" here in this case means how many possibilites do I have to distribute the apples, but I have to give at least one apple. So to translate it to an urn model this means I have 6 apples in a box which are not the same. So 6 apples with different color and with one repetition and I pull once. So I have 6 different possibilites, but not the possibilty to grab no apple.

### For assumption c)

**Question8: This would be Stirling numbers of the second kind?**

**Question9: How would this look like in this case?** So how does the formula look like, which [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) is it and what is the result?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is that the exact wording for part (c)?  Does it, for instance, say that a *particular* person has to get one apple or that *each* person has to get one apple?

Comment: Each person has to get one apple.

Comment: See also my comment following the answer of Brian Lai.

Comment: When the items are indistinguishable and the boxes (or people in this case) are distinguishable, then stars and bars is in most cases the appropriate method. Stars and bars is nice because it is highly versatile to the different assumptions you have provided and it gives a simple form of one binomial coefficient. For part $c$, we should not use stirling numbers because those only apply when the items are distinguishable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In how many ways can six apples be distributed to three persons if all the apples have to be given away?

Let $x_i$ be the number of apples person $i$ receives.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  The number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways the six apples (which we treat as indistinguishable objects) can be distributed to three persons.

A particular solution of this problem corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of six ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 1$, while
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 1 +$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 4, x_3 = 0$.  The number of such solutions is
$$\binom{6 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{8}{2} = 28$$
as you found since we must select which two of the eight positions required for six ones and two addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

In general, if we wish to distribute $k$ indistinguishable objects to $n$ distinct boxes, we must find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = k \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  Equation 2 has
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{n - 1}$$
solutions since we must choose which $n - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

The dual problem of selecting $k$ objects from $n$ types of objects, of which at least $k$ of each type are available, also leads to equation 2 and has the same number of solutions.  That type of problem is called a *combination with repetition*.

> In how many ways can up to six apples be distributed to three persons?

Since fewer than six apples may be distributed,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 6 \tag{3}$$
is an inequality in the nonnegative integers.  One way to solve this would be to find the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = k$$
for each integer $0 \leq k \leq 6$.  Doing so yields
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{k + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^6 \binom{k + 2}{2} = \binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{5}{2} + \binom{6}{2} + \binom{7}{2} + \binom{8}{2} = 84$$
Another approach is to introduce the slack variable
$$s = 6 - x_1 + x_2 + x_3$$
Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + s = 6 \tag{4}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers with the same number of solutions as inequality 3.  Using the formula stated above with $k = 6$ and $n = 4$, we obtain
$$\binom{6 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{9}{3} = 84$$
as above.

Again, we are distributing indistinguishable objects (the apples) to distinct boxes (the persons).

The two methods by which I solved this problem are related by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), which states that
$$\sum_{i = r}^{n} \binom{i}{r} = \binom{n + 1}{r + 1}$$
You can find a proof of the identity on the linked page.

> In how may ways can up to six apples be distributed to three persons if each person must receive an apple?

First, give each person an apple.  That leaves us with up to three apples to distribute to three persons, so we seek the number of solutions of the inequality
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 3 \tag{5}$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_i$ this time represents the number of additional apples we give to each person.

We introduce the slack variable
$$s = 3 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3$$
to transform the inequality into the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + s = 3 \tag{6}$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  Using the formula above, we obtain
$$\binom{3 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{6}{3} = 20$$
possible distributions.

These are not Stirling numbers of the second kind since the apples are indistinguishable and the people are distinct.  Stirling numbers of the second kind count the number of ways of distributing $n$ distinct objects to $k$ indistinguishable boxes so that no box is left empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question: How is stars and bars connected to your solution? Or is stars and bars a completely different approach for another problem and does not apply here? How would the assumption sound like, if I would have to apply the stars and bars methodology?

Comment: I did apply "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))" (in the formulation I learned it first), but I adjusted it to account for the fact that we were solving inequalities.

Comment: Ok, one last question: How is stars and bars connected to hockey-stick identity?

Comment: One way to solve the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \leq k$ is to solve the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = i$ for each $i$ such that $0 \leq i \leq k$.  For each such $i$, the number of such solutions is $\binom{i + n - 1}{n - 1}$.  Alternatively, we can introduce a slack variable $s = k - (x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n)$ so that $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n + s = k$, which is an equation in $n + 1$ nonnegative integers, which can be solved by "stars and bars" to give the expression $\binom{k + n + 1 - 1}{n + 1 - 1} = \binom{k + n}{n}$.

Comment: Equating the results of the two methods yields $$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{i + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{k + n}{n}$$ which is an application of the Hockey-Stick Identity.

Answer (score 1):

Check out "stars and bars" for some nice intuition on the problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

c) part c is probably the simplest interpretation so I'll start with that. Imagine you line up all your 6 apples ("stars"). Then you need to choose 2 dividers ("bars") to place in the 5 spots between the apples in a line. Person 1 gets the apples between the start and divider 1, person 2 gets the apples between divider 1 and divider 2, etc. So the total combinations are $5\choose2$. In general $n$ apples and $k$ people you have $n-1\choose k-1$ combinations.

a) Similar argument here but people can get 0 apples. Consider a line with $n+k-1$ spots for your $n$ apples and $k-1$ dividers. Choose $k-1$ spots for dividers and the rest to be apples. You get $n+k-1\choose k-1$ combinations. Notice now dividers can be next to eachother so people can get no apples.

b) Maybe there's a more efficient way to do this but a simple way is just to consider case a) for $0,1,\cdots,n$ apples. Then you get

$${k-1 \choose k-1} + {k \choose k-1} + \cdots+ {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$

For wolfram alpha I get the sum is

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n {i+k-1 \choose k-1} = \frac{(n + 1) {k + n \choose k - 1}}{k}  $$

Maybe you or someone else can find a nice interpretation of this :)

Comment: One alternative approach to part (b), which is mentioned in [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) is to transform the inequality $0 \leq x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 6$ to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + u = 6$, where $u$ represents the undistributed apples.  The [Hockey-Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) may be used to show the equivalence of the two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: That is correct

Question 2: From what I studied the name of it would be the number of answers to the equation in non-negative integers

Question 3: The assumption would be, all the apples would have to be given away, and each person receives at least 1 apple

Question 4: I think the correct answer would be
$sum_{k=0}^6 ({6 \choose k}* {k+2 \choose 2}) = 688$  where the first Binomial coefficient would be to choose how many apples you want to distribute and the second would be the number of different distributions.

Question 5: The correct name would be with "repetition allowed, the order does not matter"

Question 6: I think I explained in Answer 4

For assumption c: You can do the exact thing I wrote for Question 4, but instead of 6 you would have 3 cause you distributed 1 apple to each person and then started calculating the number of distributions.

If anyone reading this founds an error, I would love you to point it out to me